# Data/Type mismatch when getting Package by Name in EA

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I am writing an extension for EA and I create some packages and components programatically when I create a bottom level package I set protected property to true. Later I write a query to get this package but I get Date/Type mismatch error

**Create Package code**

```
 EA.Package  bpackage = parent.Packages.AddNew(packageComponentName, ELEMENT_TYPE_PACKAGE);
 bpackage.IsProtected = true;
 bpackage.Update();
 parent.Packages.Refresh();
 rep.RefreshModelView(parent.PackageID);
```

**SQL query to get this package**

```
  private static Boolean isBottomLevel = true; 
  public static Package getBottomLevelPackage(Repository rep, String name)
  {
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT ea_guid FROM t_package WHERE Name = '" + name + "' AND Protected = '" + isBottomLevel + "' ";
        XmlDocument xmd = runQuery(rep, sqlQuery);
        XmlNode idNode = xmd.SelectSingleNode("//ea_guid");
        return idNode != null ? rep.GetPackageByGuid(idNode.InnerText) : null;
  }
```

when I run the query I get the Data/Type mismatch error I checked the Datatype of Protected column in access and it is YES/NO

Anyone have any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has got apostrophes around the boolean value, causing it to be interpreted as a string.

```
... "' AND Protected = '" + isBottomLevel + "' ";
```

should be

```
... "' AND Protected = " + isBottomLevel;
```